# Fetch users who has checked in at particular location or page from Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to fetch the users list from Facebook Graph API 2.0 who has checked in at particular place or a page. I tried to use this way:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page

But it does not provide that information. Can this be a privacy issue?

Is there a way that if I am a page admin of the place, where people check in, I can fetch the user ids of those users?

Any kind of help or guidance will be very appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible IMHO, because the user's checkins are bound to the OAuth access restrictions, meaning that every user need to give your app the permission to request his data.

As you already refrences, the Page itself has no edge for the checkins: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page#edges